# How to define toString() method for client-side objects created from Axis2 Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, swing, netbeans, apache-axis

I'm a bit new to webservices.  I'm using Netbeans 7.0 and Axis2.  I've got Java server-side code, and a Java client.  To simplify this, I'll just use a very simple example.

I have a WorkSite class that has workSiteId, workSiteName and refCode fields, each with a getter and setter.  And on the server-side, the class also have an overridden toString() method that just returns the workSiteName.  So if I were to make a GUI server-side with a JComboBox and start adding WorkSite objects to it, the workSiteName would be what shows up in the JComboBox for each object.

So I've basically created a web method like "getWorkSiteList" that queries out of the database, creates WorkSite objects and adds them to an array, then returns the array.  I can use the WorkSite objects with no problem, except that when I look at the client-side Jax-WS "Generated Sources" in Netbeans, the getters and setters are all there, but the toString() method is not there.  So when I take my WorkSite objects out of the array and put them into a JComboBox, the combo box shows something very ugly like "examplepackagename.WorkSite.a6d35" for each item, instead of being nice and showing the workSiteName.

I guess my real question is, I have an auto-generated WorkSite.java file on the client-side in Netbeans that doesn't have my toString() method (this is called a skeleton right?); is there any way to make it include the toString() method that was defined on the server-side class?  And if not, is it safe to edit the auto-generated class (again, I think this is called a skeleton, right?) and just add my toString() method?  If I do edit the auto-generated class on the client-side, will it just get overwritten on a rebuild?

Thanks for the help!  I hope that wasn't too long winded; I just don't know all the terminology yet to explain it in a succinct manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, I worked around this by subclassing the example WorkSite class with a SubWorkSite class that does nothing but define an override toString() method that returns super.getWorkSiteName.getValue().

So I have a list of WorkSite objects that were returned from the webservice call, and I just iterate through it and for each WorkSite object in the list, I create a SubWorkSite object and add it to the JComboBox.  Now when running the app, the workSiteName is displayed in the JComboBox, instead of the ugly toString() value "examplepackagename.WorkSite.xxxxx" that you get from the auto-generated class.

I'm of course open to suggestions for doing this in a better way if anyone has any; or if anyone has more info on Stephen C's suggestion of editing the generator XSLT templates.

Answer (score 2):

The way to achieve this will be to modify the Axis2 code generator's templates.  If you look at the architecture diagram on [this page](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/Axis2ArchitectureGuide.html#bmWSDL), you will see that the code generator produces an intermediate datastructure in XML, and then uses XSLT and a set of language specific templates to emit the code.  If you want the code to include extra `toString()` methods, then the obvious approach would be to modify the templates to include support for these methods.

Caveats:

1. You'll need to understand the architecture and implementation of the generator, and the tecnologies it uses: XSLT in particular.
2. I can't guarantee that there is sufficient information in the intermediate XML files to generate the methods you need.  (I expect there will be, but I haven't looked.)

Comment: Good info Stephen C, thanks for the reply. I looked all around the web to try to find more info on this, like where the templates are at and which one to edit for a Java client, and came up with nothing really useful. I also looked for these template somewhere on my dev box but came up empty.  Do you have any idead?

Comment: I thought that maybe the less-ideal way to do this might be to just subclass my auto-generated client-side classes, and define the toString() method in the subclasses.  Then when I get an array of WorkSite objects, I can just create SubWorkSite objects from them where the toString() method is defined, give those to the JComboBox so it shows the name I want, and then if I need to send a SubWorkSite object back to the server I can cast it back to the auto-generated WorkSite class.  Do you see any issue with that approach?  (other than seeming noobish)

Comment: Yea, there's an issue.  How do you convince the client-side code to reify the instances using your subclasses rather than the generated classes?

Comment: So my webmethod returns a List<WorkSite>, and I just iterate this list and for each item, I create a SubWorkSite object, then add it to the GUI's JComboBox.